# After creating managed released package can we create new class or visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, class

I have managed released package and i want to create new class and visualforce page in same managed released package. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can't delete classes and things right now (there are some elements that you can delete and more are coming) but you can add new ones.

Simply add them to the org where you create the package, go to the package, choose to add components and they should be available for selection in the exact same manner that as when you created the package the first time around.